# Form loaded with jquery is not fully working, any ideas why?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I load a form with jQuery's .load() function from one page of the site into another. The injected form verifies inputs as expected, and goes to thank you page on submit, but the database doesn't get the new entry. The form works fine in the original page. Any ideas why the database update never happens if I inject it? 
I have no access to the source code so I don't know how the database gets updated in the backend. I can only add more JavaScript.

Comment: do you have any event handler assigned to the form which updates the db.. if so try to use event delegation

Comment: I am not assigning events or anything else to the form. I am just loading it. As far as I can see the form submission is not getting handled via JS, it is just a  <form  method="post" action="/form/confirm.htm">

Comment: Do you think there might be some sort of restriction in the back end?